# how select text automatically and save to csv/excel using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am developing one selenium web driver application, in that application automatically one web page will open and that web page contains one table, so my next goal is, I want to copy(scrape) first row of that table and have to save in csv file, to achieve it what I have to use? please anyone help me.

Code:

```
from selenium import web driver
from web driver _manager. chrome import Chrome Driver Manager
import time
from selenium. web driver. chrome. options import Options
web = web driver. Chrome(Chrome Driver Manager().install())
web.get('http://ts.vcccms.in/CCMSPDI/FindLogs/Index')
time .sleep(4)
device_id = "slcs010928"
div_id = web.find_element_by_x path ("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input")
div_id.send_keys(device_id)
time.sleep(4)

submit = web.find_element_by_x path("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/button")
submit.click()
time.sleep(4)

download = web.find_element_by_x path("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/a[3]/span")
download.click()
time.sleep(4)
web.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't use Selenium here. You can get the data from the XHR and a simple request. Then I'd use `pandas` to grab the the first row and use `.to_csv()`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

device_id = "slcs010928"

url = 'http://ts.vcccms.in/CCMSPDI/FindLogs/GetFindLogs'
payload = {
'DeviceID': device_id,
'_': '1631010215983'    }

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData)
first_row = df.iloc[[0], :]

# The line below could essentially take the place of the 2 lines above
#first_row = pd.DataFrame(jsonData[0], index=[0])

first_row.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(first_row.to_string())
                                                                                                                                                                            meterData   CCMSBoxID          Time Latitude Longitude Voltage Current Power  Kvah Frequency    PF ApparentPower ActivePower  CummulativePower BatteryPercentage  TamperSwitchStatus  MCBStatus  ContractorStatus sTamperSwitchStatus sMCBStatus sContractorStatus GsmSignalStrength  VoltageStatus sVoltageStatus MaximumDemand MaximumDemandDate MaximumDemandKVA MaximumDemandKVADate TamperCount             SimNumber  RelayStatus sRelayStatus  WDTCount DeviceCheck MeterType  LightStatus  KeypadMode ScheduleOnTime ScheduleOffTime miscellaneousdata  EmergencyMode EmergencyStatus PoweronHours  DoorStatus sDoorStatus  Emergencyflag RTUStatus          RecivedTime ProtocolType
0  ~|23|010928|210907154508|24600|0000|026|5000|0003|0000|0014056|0000000|0000|000000000000|0000|000000000000|0000000|0000|8991000904215891255F|0|1|1|0|0|74|1800,0600|000|00200025|~  SLCS010928  210907154508     None      None     246       0  None     0        50  0.26         0.003           0             14056              None                   0          0                 1                None       None              Open                74              1           None          0000              None             0000                 None        0000  8991000904215891255F            0         None         0        None      None            0           0          18:00           06:00          00200025              0             OFF      0000000           0       Close              0   Working  07-09-2021 15:45:14         Http
```

Comment: If it worked out, be sure to accept the solution